# iFrame resizer with chrome 67 causes flickering

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, iframe-resizer

We have an iframe resizer in use with the default settings.
Until the upgrade to chrome 67 it worked fine.
When I am using chrome 67 on a macbook pro (13") every change in the view causes the screen to flicker.
When used on an external monitor it works fine, also works fine on firefox.

We couldn't find any known issue on chrome, but this is a pretty new version.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this issue if someone will encounter this in the future.
This is a bug in chrome.
We contacted the chromium team and they are on it.
You can follow the discussion here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=852348